# Why typescript doesn't know that i checked for object type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to build such a function:

```
const recursionProxy = <T extends object>(subject: T) =>
  new Proxy(subject, {
    get(target, key: keyof T) {
      const nestedSubject = target[key];

      if (typeof nestedSubject === "object") {
        return recursionProxy(nestedSubject);
      }

      return nestedSubject ?? target._ ?? "Message not set";
    },
  });
```

but under the line `recursionProxy(nestedSubject);` there is an error that says

```
[i] Argument of type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object'.
```

why typescript doesn't take that if staement in consideration,
in side the if statement `nestedSubject` is of type object

Comment: BTW, `typeof null === 'object'` - so you need to also check for `nestedSubject !== null`

Comment: In JS, `null` is of "type" `"object"`, but in TS, `null` does NOT extend `object`... https://tsplay.dev/mAQyRm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does seem to work if you use a type predicate :

```
const isObject = (f: any): f is object => {
   if(typeof f === "object") return true;
return false;
}
const recursionProxy = <T extends object>(subject: T) =>
  new Proxy(subject, {
    get(target, key: keyof T) {
      const nestedSubject = target[key];

      if (isObject(nestedSubject)) {
        return recursionProxy(nestedSubject);
      }

      return nestedSubject ?? target._ ?? "Message not set";
    },
  });
```

[Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlhA8gIwFYFNiwLwwBQBmAXDAIZgCeAlCQfBDCGpjgHwwDeAsAFAz9wCeKBQAO6EHTrYZMAERMMWOVRgAndFACuasDChqt6ANy8N23TAKkANhBO8Avr1CRYG4DohxwABTUgAB4UMLgAPAAqMOiBUOhgACYMiiyseBBazFgkEarYrLz8YOgA7jD+QRTpmUpQADSchfwwAOaawqRqbfUwANboFCT9FJIwuY18zfyu0DDF0OgJAMo1LKH6nd0A2sMAuqY8TVOC+AgotXjzccurWFSq3JNT-OY6eh5ePmAVwZfoCzcslAqAdnjBnIcns1XpYrosVkCYAB+JEbLqaAB0AH1kai5ABZf4QUhtOYgWD2KByUHNRx1JqOEG8IA)

A null check can also be added in the predicate, if that is required:

```
const isObject = (f: any): f is object => {
  if(f === null) return false;
   if(typeof f === "object") return true;
return false;
}
```